# Angular2 FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, download, filesaver.js

I'm using FileSaver.js with angular 2 and it works pretty well; however, I'm getting a semantic error in my build:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'saveAs'

I'm using the angular 2 seed and added the library to my project.config like this:

```
this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES = [
      ...this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES,
{src: 'file-saver/FileSaver.min.js', inject: true},

    ];


this.SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV.paths['file-saver'] =
        `${this.APP_BASE}node_modules/file-saver/FileSaver`;

    this.SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG.packages['file-saver'] = {
      main: 'FileSaver.js',
      defaultExtension : 'js'
    };
```

I can use saveAs in my component:

```
downloadFile(data: any){

        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });

        //saveAs is a function in the FileSaver.js library https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js
        saveAs(blob, "results.csv");
    }
```

The problem is that the semantic error causes my build to fail when pushed to my cloud environment.

I've tried adding the typing via:

```
npm i @types/file-saver
```

This allows me to import:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
```

However, this gives me the error:

> h.saveAs is not a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually just figured it out. I needed to delcare the variable in order for typescript to use it:

```
declare var saveAs:any;
```

Answer (score 4):

Since there aren't any typings for FileSaver, I used the following approach.

For **Typescript 1.8** you can import using

1. Downloaded FileSaver.js from below link and saved in my project directory.

> https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js

2.Then in component I wanted to use FileSaver, I loaded the saved FileSaver.js and assigned a reference to it using

> let fileSaver = require('../../assets/js/FileSaver');

Right after my imports.

Now anywhere i wanted to save the file using FileSaver, I would to call it using

> fileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);

However, for **Typescript 2.x** you can import using

```
import * as filesaver from '../../assets/js/FileSaver';
```

and use it as:

> fileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);

Answer (score 3):

Other solution would be to install FileSaver type package

```
npm install --save @types/filesaver
```

Since TSConfig is by default looking in the directory @types/* for types, it will be automatically recognized in your whole code/application.

Comment: I tried doing this, but getting the error mentioned above h.saveAs is not a function