# Angular 2: File Saver

Tags: angular, download, filesaver.js

iam trying to implement a download button in my Angular 2 application.
I have used these tutorials: 
http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/
https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-cli-adding-third-party-libraries

So i installed file-saver by: npm install angular-file-saver

But import FileSaver from 'file-saver'; or import FileSaver from 'angular-file-saver'; doesnt work.

Error: Cannot find module 'file-saver'.

How do i get this working?

Thank you

Comment: For angular-cli you can follow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41493844/4309299 Good Luck!

Comment: see my working answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51589031/741251

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/ is a AngularJS service so it won't work for Angular2.

Refer to the one of the many SO questions already answered

- [Angular 2 Best approach to use FileSaver.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240796/angular-2-best-approach-to-use-filesaver-js)
- [Use Filesaver js with angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782331/use-filesaver-js-with-angular2)
- [Angular2 FileSaver.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978750/angular2-filesaver-js)